# Bound datagrid column text format not changing

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, .net-4.5

I've created a database table using DB browser for SQLite where each of the columns are of type `text`. Now there is a column in the said table which is in the string format **yyyy-MM-dd** but when I want to see that columns data in a datagrid I want it to show in the format **dd-MM-yyyy**.

First I tried it like

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" Width="800" Height="400" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            ...
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="DueDate" Width="100" Binding="{Binding DueDate, StringFormat='dd-MM-yyyy'}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            ...
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

But it didn't work.

Then I added the below code in my codebehind

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(DateTime), typeof(String))]
public class DateTimeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return DateTime.ParseExact(value.ToString(), "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and then added the below codes to XAML

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SQLiteTest"
....
<Window.Resources>
    <local:DateTimeConverter x:Key="converter"/>
</Window.Resources>
...
<DataGridTextColumn Header="DueDate" Width="100" Binding="{Binding DueDate,Converter={ StaticResource converter}, StringFormat=dd-MM-yyyy}"></DataGridTextColumn>
```

But when I run the code I get the error

> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

on the line `return DateTime.ParseExact(value.ToString(), "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Can anyone help me with this?

**EDIT:**

I'm doing the filter query in a button click event like

```
    using(SQLiteConnection conn= new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=TestDB.db;"))
    {
        conn.Open();

        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM billdata WHERE DueDt >= date('now','-1 days') AND DueDt < date('now','+10 days') AND PaidOn = '' ORDER BY DueDt", conn);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        
        SQLiteDataAdapter adap = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command);
        
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("SrcData");
        adap.Fill(dt);
        
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource=dt.DefaultView;
        
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: The .NET DateTime doesn't recognize the input as a DateTime it understands, meaning that it is not formatted like dd-MM-yyyy, which makes sense to me because no database will store dates that way. What does value.ToString() look like?

Comment: @JohnV value.ToString() looks something like `2022-03-15`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your first attempt is the data isn't a DateTime, so it can't convert it.

For the Value Converter, the problem is that the converter expects a string in the format "dd-MM-yyyy", which not the format of the dates in the database. Instead of ParseExact and a specific format, just use the regular DateTime parsing functions if the database format is yyyy-MM-dd.

```
if (DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString(), out var dt))
{  
      return dt;
}
else
{
      return string.Empty; //return whatever you want to indicate that the data was bad
}
```

I prefer using DateTime.TryParse because it will not throw an exception if parsing fails. Then you can just return whatever makes sense for your UI.

As an aside, instead of messing with the tables in raw text format, if you know a column is a date time, then convert the values to a date time when you read them in. Parsing to a date time in the converter and then formatting the output is kind of inefficient. You could convert each row in the data table to a representative object (including parsing the date times), and then bind your DataGrid to that collection of objects.

Comment: Well doing `return DateTime.ParseExact(value.ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` did the trick.

Comment: Yes that will work, it will just throw an exception if it comes across a string it can't parse, which would be bad in a production application.

Comment: I know that the column I'm doing filter on is a datetime but when creating the database SQLite does not have a datetype type, so the data is stored in the database as string with format yyyy-MM-dd. BTW, I've added some code in my question on how I'm adding the filtered data to datagrid. Maybe you can suggest how can I do what you are suggesting after seeing that

Comment: Are you responsible for creating the database?

Comment: Yes... obviously using  DB browser for SQLite like I mentioned in my question

Comment: I was referring to the design of the database schema. I know that you made this specific copy of the database. It's not clear from the question if the database is something completely internal to your application or if it's an input to your application from something external that you don't control. In any, case, I would open a new question if you want to do something like that.

Comment: the database is something completely internal to my application